# Efficient use of LINQ - Indexing

Tags: c#, linq, winforms, ienumerable

I have a Class with a List of objects, and those objects contain a list which has lists to objects in the first class, and I'm trying to quickly index them.  Simplified:

```
class Person
{
    public IEnumberable<HistoricalEvent> Events
    {
        get
        {
            return World.HistoricalEvents.Values.Where(x=>x.PeopleInvolved.Contains(this));
        }
    }
}
```

Also

```
class HistoricalEvent
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<HistoricalFigure> PeopleInvolved
    {
        get { return Enumerable.Empty<People>(); }
    }
...
}
```

and a subclass

```
class HistoricalEventSubclass : HistoricalEvent
{
    Person person1 = new Person("Alice");
    Person person2 = new Person("Bob");        

    public override IEnumerable<Person> PeopleInvolved
    {
        get
        {
            yield return person1;
            yield return person2;
        }
    }       
    ...
}
```

The Events class is called from a method using: `frm.grpHistoricalFigureEvents.FillListboxWith(frm.lstHistoricalFigureEvents, Events);`

```
    internal static void FillListboxWith(this GroupBox groupbox, ListBox listbox, IEnumerable<object> objects)
    {
        if (objects == null || !objects.Any())
        {
            groupbox.Visible = false;
            return;
        }
        groupbox.Visible = true;
        listbox.BeginUpdate();
        listbox.Items.Clear();
        listbox.Items.AddRange(objects.ToArray());
        listbox.EndUpdate();
        listbox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        var title = groupbox.Text.Split('(')[0].Trim();
        groupbox.Text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", title, listbox.Items.Count);
    }
```

The problem is that calling Events takes a long time (as World.HistoricalEvents can be a very big List).  Is there a more time-efficient way of doing this?

Part of the slowdown is that Events is converted ToArray() and shoved into a listbox, and so I'll also be pursuing an alternative such as a listbox which can handle an IEnumberable directly.

Comment: If there is more code, please provide that.  Unlike SO, we don't work with simplified code.

Comment: You should profile it to see where the real slowdowns are, but my gut tells me a big win could be had by implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on Person and changing `PeopleInvoled` to be [ISet<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Then, use a [HashSet<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) for the underlying implementation.  This makes more sense from a domain perspective, as a person's involvement with an event is binary - it makes no sense that they would appear twice.

Comment: You are correct that ToArray() is a likely slowdown.  Ditto if you use ToList().  If you have 100K events, your code is held up until all 100K events are collected, despite the use of yield.  Consider using a BindSource.DataSource, which accepts an IEnumerable collection.

Comment: @Jamal, Added the last step in the chain of this, there is a ton more code and I don't want to get bogged down in unrelated issues otherwise though.

Comment: @RickDavin, as far as I can tell a BindingSource.DataSource isn't polymorphic, and the Events Method returns a set of Events which may be of many subclasses, only one was shown, so it doesn't work in those cases.  Is there an alternative that is polymorphic or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

How do you load the data for events and people? If you can denormalise your data so that a person has a materialised Set/List of events they are involved in I suspect you would gain a lot of performance (at the cost of a bit of memory).

Here is some pseudo code to explain what I mean:

```
var personStore = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
var eventStore = new Dictionary<string, Event>();
foreach (var eventData in eventSource)
{
  var event = new Event(eventData);
  eventStore[eventData.Name] = event;

  foreach (var personData in eventData)
  {
    // Is this the first time we've seen this person?
    if (!personStore.HasKey(personData.Name)
    {
      personStore[personData.Name] = new Person(personData);
    }

    var person = personStore[personData.Name];

    // This creates the bidirectional mapping which makes lookups
    // in either direction fast.
    event.PeopleInvolved.Add(person);
    person.Events.Add(event);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Great question, that is essentially the set up I had prior to attempting this alternative.  If I couldn't find a good enough improvement I was planning on rolling back to this alternative.

The problem is that each of the event subclasses handled associated people differently and so this option allowed me to drop a huge amount of custom association code in 30+ classes, which was a big win.  Lots of balancing factors.